# Passing a hash to a defined type in puppet/erb

Tags: linux, erb, puppet

I'm trying to use a hash for the first time in puppet, so in my nodes.pp I'm going to use this:

```
node test1.example.com {
    netset::int::vconf {"servers" :
        label1 => { 'comment' => 'VIP Test1', 'ipaddress' => '192.168.1.10', 'netmask' => '255.255.255.0', 'int_label' => 'TEST1' },
        label2 => { 'comment' => 'VIP Test2', 'ipaddress' => '192.168.1.11', 'netmask' => '255.255.255.0', 'int_label' => 'TEST2' },
    }
}
```

In the file /etc/puppet/modules/netset/int/vconf.pp that I am writing I'm creating a defined type:

```
define netset::int::vconf ($comment,$ipaddress){...do somethings...}
```

My questionis how do I pass each keys of the hashes to the defined type? Somehow I'm imagining I'm going to have to create a loop somewhere, any help would be of great assistance.

Thanks Dan

Answer (score 1):

Puppet (yet) doesn't support loops. So what you basically want is to create a hash and pass it to puppet function "create_resources()". So, in your case, it would look something like:

```
$my_hash = {
  'label1' => {
    'comment'   => 'VIP Test1',
    'ipaddress' => '192.168.1.10',
    'netmask'   => '255.255.255.0',
    'int_label' => 'TEST1'
  },
  'label2' => {
    'comment'   => 'VIP Test2',
    'ipaddress' => '192.168.1.11',
    'netmask'   => '255.255.255.0',
    'int_label' => 'TEST2'
   },
}
```

And after that:

```
create_resources(::netset::int::vconf, $my_hash)
```

So, it's basically the same as if you have written something like this:

```
::netset::int::vconf { 'label1' :
  'comment'   => 'VIP Test1',
  'ipaddress' => '192.168.1.10',
  'netmask'   => '255.255.255.0',
  'int_label' => 'TEST1'
},

::netset::int::vconf  { 'label2' :
  'comment'   => 'VIP Test2',
  'ipaddress' => '192.168.1.11',
  'netmask'   => '255.255.255.0',
  'int_label' => 'TEST2'
}
```